# Inverter a ordem de palavras separadas com str_replace no PHP

Tags: php

Tenho uma string

```
opção1_opção2_opção3
```

usei str_replace pra separar as opções

```
$titulo = str_replace("_"," ",$titulo );
```

tenho como saída

```
opção1 opção2 opção3
```

Gostaria de inverter a ordem para ficar assim:

```
opção3 opção2 opção1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para isso você pode usar uma combinação das funções [explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php), [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reverse.php) e [implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) e assim terá o resultado desejado, até porque a função "[str_replace](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php)" serve mais para limpar dados de uma string.

```
<?php
// Seu texto
$texto = "opção1_opção2_opção3";

// Quebra o texto nos "_" e transforma cada pedaço numa matriz
$divisor = explode("_", $texto);

// Inverte os pedaços
$reverso = array_reverse($divisor);

// Junta novamente a matriz em texto
$final = implode(" ", $reverso); // Junta com espaço
$final2 = implode("_", $reverso); // Junta com traço

// Imprime os resultados na tela
echo $final;
echo "\r\n";
echo $final2;
?>
```

Comment: Valeu man, é isso!!!