# Como inverter data

Tags: php, string, variáveis

Estou tentando inverter uma variável de data que exibe os resultados assim:

```
2016/05/20
```

Porém quero uma função em php que exiba assim:

```
20/05/2016
```

Como fazer isso?

Comment: Como já tem respostas, acho que já dá pra apontar pra outra. Na outra tem até coisas a mais do que você precisa, mas praticamente o que poderia sair de resposta aqui já está contido na de lá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes fazer isso com o `data()` e o `stringtotime()` assim:

```
echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("2016/05/20"));
```

#### Exemplo: https://ideone.com/rzIRY0

Outra opção é tratar como uma string normal, fazer split com `explode()`, inverter a ordem com `array_reverse()` e juntar numa string de novo com `implode()`. Nesse caso seria algo assim:

```
echo implode("/", array_reverse(explode("/", "2016/05/20")));
```

Exemplo: https://ideone.com/PRREDi

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou corretamente.
Muito grato!

Answer (score 1):

Eu já respondi algo semelhante à uns dias atrás, caso queria ver a reposta está [nesse tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/115728/inverter-a-ordem-de-palavras-separadas-com-str-replace-no-php/115730#115730) ... e o conceito é o mesmo você deve "quebrar" sua string nas barras "/" com a função "[explode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.explode.php)" e depois juntar elas de novo com a função "[implode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php)", eu usei a função "[array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-reverse.php)" para fazer a inversão, mas como é uma data você poderia fazer isso manualmente.

**Exemplo usado inversão pelo PHP**

```
<?php
// Sua data
$data = "2016/05/20";

// Quebra a data nos "/" e transforma cada pedaço numa matriz
$divisor = explode("/", $data);

// Inverte os pedaços da data (via PHP)
$reverso = array_reverse($divisor);

// Junta novamente a matriz em texto
$final = implode("/", $reverso);

// Imprime os resultados na tela
echo $final;
?>
```

**Exemplo invertendo "manualmente"**

```
<?php
// Sua data
$data = "2016/05/20";

// Quebra a data nos "/" e transforma cada pedaço numa variavel
list($ano, $mes, $dia) = explode("/", $data);

// Monta a data de volta no formato certo
$data_nova = ($dia . "/" . $mes . "/" . $ano);

// Imprime os resultados na tela
echo $data_nova;
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou corretamente.
Muito grato a todos vocês.

Answer (score 0):

Caso estiver programando de forma procedural uma opção é usar a função `date_format`:

```
$date = date_create("2016/05/08");
echo date_format($date,"d/m/Y");
```

Caso você estiver usando a abordagem de Orientação a Objetos pode usar `format`:

```
$data_string = '2016/05/08';
$data = new DateTime($data_string);
echo $data->format('d/m/Y');
```

Mas é uma pergunta com n soluções possíveis.

---

Referências:

[date_format doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php)

[Pergunta equivalente - SO[en]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

[Datetime doc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou corretamente.
Muito grato!